# fallback image for flash object

Tags: flash, object, fallback

If i want a image to show if this flash cannot be loaded how do i do that?

```
<object width="574" height="143">
<param name="movie" value="/upload/attachments/1391/139130/iphone_banner.swf">
<embed src="/upload/attachments/1391/139130/iphone_banner.swf" width="574" height="143">
</embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could wrap the `object` tag in a `div` and apply a `background-image` to the `div`.

CSS:

```
.wrapper
{
    background: url(path/to/image.png);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <object..
</div>
```