# html - how to place content in an pdf embed tag?

Tags: jquery, html, adobe-reader

In html code I have the `<embed></embed>` tag to display pdf files on the web. But the problem is I need to account for cases where the user doesn't have the adobe plugin installed or has it but has the web viewer setting disabled. So basically I need to detect if the the pdf displays or not.

I thought of doing something like this `<embed>Please install the acrobat plugin.</embed>`,
because if it did work then it should display the pdf on top of the text thus hiding the text, but if the pdf didn't show, then the text would show.

But when I tested this, it didn't work. When I looked in the IE9 developer tools, the "Please install the acrobat plugin." text was outside the embed tag... It was like this:

```
<embed/>
Please install the acrobat plugin.
</embed>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: You could try what was suggested in this answer, use a background image.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801615/fallback-image-for-flash-object

Comment: I still dont understand how to do this. Can you provide an example?