# replace flash with image in php

Tags: php, image, flash

I am newby in  php and i have a small problem.

I have a flash in my index php, like this

```
<div class="flash">
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
            if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
                alert("This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js.");
            } else {
               AC_FL_RunContent(
                    'codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0',
                    'width', '903',
                    'height', '301',
                    'src', 'swf/whatever',
                    'quality', 'high',
                    'pluginspage', 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
                    'align', 'middle',
                    'play', 'true',
                    'loop', 'true',
                    'scale', 'showall',
                    'wmode', 'transparent',
                    'devicefont', 'false',
                    'id', 'whatever',
                    'bgcolor', '#ffffff',
                    'name', 'whatever',
                    'menu', 'true',
                    'allowFullScreen', 'false',
                    'allowScriptAccess','sameDomain',
                    'movie', 'swf/whatever',
                    'salign', ''
                    ); //end AC code
            }
        /* ]]> */
        </script>
</div>
```

i want an image there where flash cannot be displayed, let's say iOS systems.
ex.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: PHP does not know about the user's browser's ability to display flash. You would have to use JavaScript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801615/fallback-image-for-flash-object

Comment: @Jens - You could check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` to check what kind of browser the client is running. Of course this value could be forged but in most cases it should work.

Comment: @KristerAndersson: True, but even if you know that I'm using Firefox (or Chrome or whatever...) that doesn't mean I've flash installed.

Comment: @Jens - No, that's correct. But you could check for iPad or iPhones etc=)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following trick:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
            if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {

                document.write("<img src='/path/to/image.png'>");

                } else {
    ...
                }
            /* ]]> */
        </script>
```

If you show an alert window with the text "This page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js." using the original page code the previous example should work.

If don't show the warning nor the flash content you should change the line

```
    if (AC_FL_RunContent == 0) {
```

for

```
   if (typeof AC_FL_RunContent === 'undefined') {
```

The difference is that in the first piece of code the variable `AC_FL_RunContent` must be created to work properly. The second code checks if the variable actually exists.

You colud mix both methods.

Good luck.